# placing of image and text at the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I need to place an image and text at the bottom of the div which contains text. After following various posts about this question I have come up with this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sidztalal/708c9nqw/16/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div id="col-lg-4" class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="cta-text">
        <h3>Heading text that Can span 2 or 3 lines</h3>
      </div>
      <p><strong>Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications. With Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and JavaScript, it forms a triad of cornerstone technologies for the World Wide Web</strong></p>
      <div class="cta-text">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="~/img/icon2.png" /></td>
            <td valign="middle">
              <a href="#">
                <p><strong>More Info!</strong></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">


      <div class="cta-text">
        <h3>Heading text that Can span 2 or 3 lines</h3>
      </div>
      <p><strong>Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications.</strong></p>
      <div class="cta-text">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="~/img/icon2.png" /></td>
            <td valign="middle">
              <a href="#">
                <p><strong>More Info!</strong></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="cta-text">
        <h3>Heading text that Can span 2 or 3 lines</h3>
      </div>
      <p><strong>Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications. With Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and JavaScript.</strong></p>
      <div class="cta-text">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="~/img/icon2.png" /></td>
            <td valign="middle">
              <a href="#">
                <p><strong>More Info!</strong></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .col-lg-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.cta-text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
}

table {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.cta-text h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  color: #d9232d;
}
```

However on browser resizing absolute position of the table makes it overlap with the rest of the text. Please suggest an approach which avoids the overlapping of image and above text, also if I can structure the HTML better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your *.col-lg-4* an inline-grid and set the last row to a fixed height, e.g.

```
display: inline-grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto 4em;
```

and then you can get rid of the absolute positioned table.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle so you can see the desire result.
[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/708c9nqw/59/).

I achieve this using `flex`. I also added extra container for paragraph/text with fixed height and overflow should be hidden. It's easy if you can try it with bootstrap4; in this case you just need to set the paragraph/text container height and that's it.

Comment: as the heading could be of single or multiple lines, what worked for was using extra container as well as using approach mentioned below by Holzchopf , thanks

Comment: The solution work in both cases either multiple lines of heading or single line and UI would remain responsive.

Answer (score 1):

i solved my issue with using div for my text with fixed height and overflow hidden as described by @Azhar above

```
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Also included approach mentioned by @Holzchopf

```
display: inline-grid;
grid-template-rows:6em auto auto;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/708c9nqw/70/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to move your col-lg paddings to a new div inside it (inside col-lg). Add another 
   `div` inside col-lg, then move your paddings there.
2. I think for this case (bottom link), it would be easier if you use `div` or `span` rather than `table` or `td`. set it to `display:inline;` or `display:block;`. You can also adjust it with `width: 100%;`